# ActiveRocord query with polymorphic associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to get some records from table, but i don't know how to build this query.

I have some models.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications, as: :source
  has_many :decisions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source, polymorphic: true
end

class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications, as: :source
  belongs_to :request
end
```

So, I need to get all Notifications where source = some_request or source.request = some_request

Comment: By `some_request` I assume you mean it's an instance of `Request`?  If so then why not just use the association?  `some_request.notifications`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it something simple as -

```
some_request.notifications
# or
some_decision.notifications
```

and if source is combination of request & decision then

```
notifications_ids = some_request.notifications.pluck(:id) +
some_decision.notifications.pluck(:id)

Notification.find(notifications_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be `Notification.where(source_id: some_request.id, source_type: 'Request')`

Refer [Active record association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)